# A "stacktrace" for errors

Tags: errors, debugging

Is it possible to get some kind of "stacktrace" in TeX errors? I sometimes get errors which only show some deep LaTeX internals, but nothing about which LaTeX macro referenced it.

Thanks,

Comment: See also answers in [macros - What does \errorcontextlines do? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35252/what-does-errorcontextlines-do)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While "stacktracing" might not be possible since the state of macro expansion can be indeterminate (*a priori* and *a posteriori*). However, widening the context of your error reporting might provide some sense of where you are and what's going on.  Try something like `\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{999}` for this.  For myself, liberally sprinkling my code with lots of `\typeout`'s or `PackageWarning` (*et al*.) lines provides most of what I need (write a routine that switches these on and off according to a global flag you set).  Of course, many packages accept a `debug` or `verbose` option that dumps lots more state info to the .log file. Otherwise, the big gun is the  [trace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/trace) package to give good control over `\tracingall`.  The manual provided with it contains some worked examples and useful words of advice.  Other words of wisdom can be found [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-erroradvice) (contains such pearls as: "The best advice to those faced with TeX errors is *not to panic*.").

Comment: You can't use `\setcounter` here: you need to use the plain TeX `\errrocontextlines 999\relax`.

Comment: Actually you can use \setcounter: latex.ltx contains the line \let\c@errorcontextlines\errorcontextlines

Comment: Now this I did not know: I always stick with the plain TeX approach to \errorcontextlines (as it's a primitive in any case)