# How can I distinguish between error in code and bug in package?

Tags: compiling, emacs, algorithm2e, org-mode

I keep getting an error upon compilation, but cannot find an error, even with a tiny reproducible example (below). I am exporting from Emacs `org-mode` to LaTeX and then PDF, I am receiving the [well known error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71384/latex-debugging-strategies-and-brace-mismatching) message:

```
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### simple group (level 1) entered at line 1061 ({)
### bottom level
```

The issue is that `line 1061` is stated as the problem, regardless of the length of my org-file and the actual .tex file. I can reproduce the error with the following part of code, down to which I have narrowed the problem. The intermediary `.tex` file being only 56 lines long and the error message persisting as above!

I cannot find any errors (at least regarding syntax!). Here it is in directly from the LaTeX source that is compiled:

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \KwIn{input}
  \Repeat{something} {
      scroll to bottom of page\;
  }
  \caption{a caption}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

And here it is in the org file (no errors  are produced from org mode to .tex file, only at the compilation stage, exporting to PDF):

```
#+latex_header: \usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,lined,end]{algorithm2e}
#+begin_src latex 
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \KwIn{input}
    \Repeat{something} {
        scroll to bottom of page\;
    }
    \Return{something else}
    \caption{a caption}
  \end{algorithm}
#+end_src
```

I have tried removing all the options specified in the `#+latex-header`, but that didn't make a difference - same error message pointing to line 1061.

The PDF output actually looks ok (Emacs at least doesn't halt the export procedure), which I apologise for if you have read this far - but the error messages are bugging me.

Could this be [a bug](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4078) in the {algorithm2e} package? How can I get to the root of this?

### Edit 1:

I just found a mailing list where [somebody mentions the error](https://lists.debian.org/debian-tex-maint/2016/02/msg00112.html) (only last week) and the next update of TexLive on Debian should fix it. I am not on Debian though... will a fix still work for me using TeX on OSX?

Comment: Can you repeat it with just the `{algorithm}` environment you have (inserted in a MWE)? It sounds like you have an extra `\end{stuff}` in your exported document.

Comment: First of all as Sean mentions, please post a full example such that users can test this. I just had one in a manuscript where the author had forgotten a `{` in the text.

Comment: There is no `end` option to `algorithm2e`.

Comment: I've made a smaller example that produces the same error message (on my system at least). @egreg - could you please explain a little more? I am new to LaTeX. What should I change?

Comment: @DexterMorgan Please, make it into a compilable example. Not everybody uses Org mode. I don't, for instance.

Comment: I have included everything from the .tex file that produces the error upon compilation. I am afraid I do not know what else is necessary to make it compatible for anyone. Also @egreg - I removed the `end` option and tried out all the other ones in the documentation (`longend`, `noend` and `shortend`), but the same error occurs.

Comment: As the message you linked to says the cause is a simple brace to much before `\setboolean` in line 1061. If it will be fixed depends on if someone reported it to the author and if the author did something.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "included everything from the tex" the tex you show has no `\documentclass` line at the start so will generate errors if anyone tries to test it.

Comment: Please run `M-x org-export-as-latex` and post that file for the non `org-mode` users. Your problem (here) is almost certainly with the `.tex` file, not the way Org exports and relies on LaTeX to produce a PDF.

Comment: I filed a bug report on December 15, 2015: https://lists.lirmm.fr/wws/arc/algorithm2e-discussion/2015-12/msg00000.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug in a package already reported.

Comment: @egreg Any workaround? Or is this safe to ignore? That link doesn't seem to work any more.

Comment: @cfr No, there's no workaround, I'm afraid, except making a local copy of the file and amending it. The error is often not a problem, but of course it makes TeX work inside a group, which *can* be bad for some documents.