# How to browse .tex project by line numbers in Debian?

Tags: viewers, debugging, debian, ide

I am using `\input`s in my main.tex. 
I get the following error/warning but it is difficult for me to find the line 1061 because it is in `\input` files. 
I really would like to find it. 
Now, I am using Gedit but Geany sometimes, but I have not found anything related to the debugging; I think IDE must be a solution here but not sure which; maybe, some KDE product

```
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### simple group (level 1) entered at line 1061 ({)
### bottom level
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on main.pdf (14 pages).
```

Things not helping

- `xelatex -file-line-error` because `\input` used
- ...

OS: Debian 8.5
Window manager: Gnome 3.14
TeXLive: 2016
Execution engine: XeLaTeX

Comment: The question does not make any sense. Based on experience, it does not make any sense to ask for improvement. I'm casting a close vote.

Comment: Do you mean: `pdflatex -file-line-error mytexfile.tex`? (Change `pdflatex` to the appropriate command.) See `man pdftex` for your options.

Comment: I'm surprised. What happens? Can you give some code and a sense of what error you receive?

Comment: `xelatex -file-line-error` works, but I'm afraid it is useless in this case, because the message would be exactly the same. Comment out all `\input` and uncomment them one by one until you find the faulty file.

Comment: Masi, you are using LaTeX for quite a while, and i notice your programming experience is influencing your questions. While a regular user just asks for help, you give extra information and insights. Almost all of them are completely useless, though. When LaTeX gives an error, the document f*cked up, not the software.

Comment: if you use the search feature here, and enter "line 1061", you will find that this error has been localized to the package `algorithm2e`, which has a spurious open brace on line 1061.  several people have tried to contact the maintainer, who isn't answering.  here is one case where i *would* recommend making a change in the `.sty`, giving it another name (perhaps `myalgorithm2e`) and putting a comment into any document that uses it to say what has been done.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You are right. The package of `algorithm2e` is causing the problem here too http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330698/13173

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is about a bug in a package already made known to the developer, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299516/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can not guess what the reference to KDE in your question refers to (why would KDE include a TeX debugger?), but reading the log doesn't require any special tools, and is clearly independent of your operating system.

Add

```
\tracingonline1\tracinggroups1
```

so that groups are traced then

if your main file is like

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tracingonline1\tracinggroups1
aaa

\input{\jobname a}


\input{\jobname b}

bbb

\end{document}
```

with `maina.tex` being

```
{
```

and `mainb.tex` being

```
 bbbb
```

then the log and terminal will show

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./main.aux)
(./maina.tex{entering simple group (level 1) at line 2}
) (./mainb.tex){entering output group (level 2) at line 15}
{entering vbox group (level 3) at line 15}
{leaving vbox group (level 3) entered at line 15}
{entering semi simple group (level 3) at line 15}
{entering vbox group (level 4) at line 15}
{entering hbox group (level 5) at line 15}
{leaving hbox group (level 5) entered at line 15}
{entering vbox group (level 5) at line 15}
{entering vbox group (level 6) at line 15}
{entering adjusted hbox group (level 7) at line 15}
{leaving adjusted hbox group (level 7) entered at line 15}
{leaving vbox group (level 6) entered at line 15}
{entering adjusted hbox group (level 6) at line 15}
{leaving adjusted hbox group (level 6) entered at line 15}
{leaving vbox group (level 5) entered at line 15}
{leaving vbox group (level 4) entered at line 15}
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]{leavi
ng semi simple group (level 3) entered at line 15}
{entering semi simple group (level 3) at line 15}
{leaving semi simple group (level 3) entered at line 15}
{entering semi simple group (level 3) at line 15}
{leaving semi simple group (level 3) entered at line 15}
{leaving output group (level 2) entered at line 15}
{entering vbox group (level 2) at line 15}
{leaving vbox group (level 2) entered at line 15}
{entering output group (level 2) at line 15}
{entering semi simple group (level 3) at line 15}
{leaving semi simple group (level 3) entered at line 15}
{leaving output group (level 2) entered at line 15}
{entering semi simple group (level 2) at line 15}
(./main.aux){leaving semi simple group (level 2) entered at line 15}
{entering output group (level 2) at line 15}
{entering vbox group (level 3) at line 15}
{leaving vbox group (level 3) entered at line 15}
{leaving output group (level 2) entered at line 15}
 )
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### simple group (level 1) entered at line 2 ({)
### bottom level</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 9993 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.
```

The error message tells you the problem is a simple group, that is `{` at level one (that is not nested in another group) so you can ignore all the group trace except level 1 simple groups.

Just quickly scanning the trace matching "entering" and "leaving" pairs shows that the "entering" with no matching "leaving" is

```
 (./maina.tex{entering simple group (level 1) at line 2}
```

so there you have it, the unmatched `{` is on line 2 of `maina.tex`

Comment: By this method, I think I can confirm the error is coming from `aaltothesis` .cls file where some mistakes cause the complication, since even with empty content in `\begin{document} [empty here] \end{document}` causes the error with exactly the same line number. Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330686/13173 - - How can you apply this line number inspection to .cls file?