# how to output each source line (number) during compilation (for debugging)?

Tags: errors, debugging

I have this orignal file

```
%file simples.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

which I want to compile. During compilation via `pdflatex simple.tex` there is output shown and I would like to be informed about at which line (point) the compilation is.

To make it clear I would like a feature like this

```
\typeout{line1}%file simples.tex
\typeout{line2}\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\typeout{line3}\begin{document}
\typeout{line4}\end{document}
```

which would output `line1`,`line2`,`line3`..... `linen` during the compilation.

I have made myself some shell script to inject those `\typeout{line#}` into a temporary copy of my `.tex` file.

My question, is there are `pdflatex` `tex` native way to output (or `echo`) what is currently done?

## Motivation and background

People (imho rightly) complain that `tex`'s output in case of errors is rather cryptic, which is because there is not always a guarantee that the output features a **line number** of where the error has been *caused*, but where the error eventually caused a problem, so it would benefit me greatly that at an error prompt I could always see in which line the compilation has last been.

1. a resulting pdf file simple.pdf
2. output to the console
3. a simple.log file

Is there away to include in the output each source file line before it becomes evaluated during the compilation process?

Comment: you can use `\the\inputlineno` to get the line number of the current file (which is the number that would be used in l.xxx if an error occurred at that point)

Comment: I do not understand your comment about seeing where compilation has last been, that is the line number tex shows, for example in your `\processoptionskv` question  the error is reported at the line number of  processoptionskv as tex has not yet read the rest of the package.

Comment: this is probably a feature that could be added to luatex, but as far as i can see, it's impossible to implement via macros, because of the way tex processes input.  in any event, it still may not help you, if the error is a forgotten closing brace somewhere "harmless" (with luck, that would get reported at the end of the job, with one of the "not on level 0" warning messages.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think the notion of _an error_ is a little blurry. Of course tex provides, when there is an error information about it (and as you say that includes a line and filename information). The problem is that sometimes the reason for the error occuring can relate to some codepart before as for instance in the case that you provided a misformed argument, which only upon later evaluation causes an error. Not that rarely have I read that users have had trouble spotting the exact place in their code that caused an error reported with a line number further down the road. wanted=traceback

Comment: @humanityANDpeace \errorcontext lines shows the full macro expansion call tree, line information is not possible at that point as there is no information where the macros were defined,

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? `\the\inputlineno` doesn't seem to work with macros,which is exactly how I need to use it... and I do not want simple printing out but I need to record them(in lualatex) and know them relative to my macro and the current page. It's such an easy thing but tex makes it so hard... seems to be typical of how tex works ;/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you know of any way to deal with this problem? I would hope that one doesn't, in this modern era, have to use external pre-processing to add the ability to simply get the correct source code line number? I understand that TeX is complex and designed in a funky 1970's way but it is such a simple thing. Is there any way to preprocess the symbols(hook in to TeX's symbol processor before macros or anything are handled) and create a counter on the newlines? (e.g., basically what I'd do if I were writing a pre-processing script)

Comment: It is not clear what problem you try to solve or how exactly you want the fix, getting good line number and source code links is not specifically a problem with TeX, you see similar problems in C where if you make heavy use of the pre-processor macros you find the error messages are referring to the expanded source and not the source as you see it in an editor. TeX macros are a lot more complicated than C macros, so the problem is a bit harder in TeX. But the nearest to what you ask is probably synctex which adds back linking information so you can typically get back from the preview to source

Comment: I will look in to syntex. All I need is the correct source line numbers and don't really want to do any pre-processing. When I double click on the pdf for the stuff inside \out, it does take me there so it does have that referencing that I need. Do you know how to get this info this off hand? Probably have to parse the syntex file? The main problem is if that is the case is that it is probably written after all processing is done so not way to get the correct state except run twice.

Comment: that will just print the value of \inputlineno at the point the output routine was invoked which is only partially related to the line numbers of any source lines of text that end up on that page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, It seems to be broken for `\include`. 
Page = 1, Line = 71
[1]
Page = 2, Line = 71
[2]
--Caching starts here
Page = 3, Line = 3
[3]
Page = 4, Line = 5
[4]
Page = 5, Line = 5
[5])
Page = 6, Line = 2
[6]
Page = 7, Line = 2
--Caching ends here
[7]
Page = 8, Line = 81
[8]
Page = 9, Line = 81
[9]
Page = 10, Line = 83
[10]
Page = 11, Line = 85. 

It works fine when the caching does not take place. Which simply means I insert the code in place rather than dump it to a file and use `\include`.

Comment: `\inputlineno` isn't affected by `\include` (other than the obvious effect that it refers to lines in the other file) but as I said above it relates to where tex has got to in the source files, and only has a slight accidental connection to the page any text gets typeset on in the end, but this isn't a discussion forum there are far too many comments here and the system will start objecting soon:-)

Answer (score 0):

In LuaLaTeX it's possible... (see `ltluatex` and `luatex` documentation)

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
% ======== begin main code ========
\usepackage{currfile}
\directlua{
luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer', function() print(tex.inputlineno, token.get_macro("currfilename")) end, "function to print current file and line number")
}
% ======== end main code ========
\begin{document}
aaa

aaa

aaa

aaa
\end{document}
```

If you want the full file name as well, see
[compiling - How to easily determine the full name of the latex file when a build error occurs? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116173/how-to-easily-determine-the-full-name-of-the-latex-file-when-a-build-error-occur) and
[Full path of current file - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42417/full-path-of-current-file).

The output looks roughly like this

```
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
 L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/currfile/currfile.sty (/usr/share/texm
f-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/
generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex
/filehook/filehook.sty (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook-2020.sty)))8  a.tex
9       a.tex
 (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def1       l3backend-luatex.def
2       l3backend-luatex.def
3       l3backend-luatex.def
4       l3backend-luatex.def
5       l3backend-luatex.def
6       l3backend-luatex.def
7       l3backend-luatex.def
8       l3backend-luatex.def
9       l3backend-luatex.def
10      l3backend-luatex.def
11      l3backend-luatex.def
12      l3backend-luatex.def
13      l3backend-luatex.def
14      l3backend-luatex.def
15      l3backend-luatex.def
16      l3backend-luatex.def
17      l3backend-luatex.def
18      l3backend-luatex.def
19      l3backend-luatex.def
20      l3backend-luatex.def
21      l3backend-luatex.def
22      l3backend-luatex.def
23      l3backend-luatex.def
24      l3backend-luatex.def
25      l3backend-luatex.def
26      l3backend-luatex.def
27      l3backend-luatex.def
28      l3backend-luatex.def
29      l3backend-luatex.def
30      l3backend-luatex.def
31      l3backend-luatex.def
32      l3backend-luatex.def
33      l3backend-luatex.def
34      l3backend-luatex.def
35      l3backend-luatex.def
36      l3backend-luatex.def
37      l3backend-luatex.def
38      l3backend-luatex.def
39      l3backend-luatex.def
40      l3backend-luatex.def
41      l3backend-luatex.def
42      l3backend-luatex.def
43      l3backend-luatex.def
44      l3backend-luatex.def
45      l3backend-luatex.def
46      l3backend-luatex.def
47      l3backend-luatex.def
48      l3backend-luatex.def
49      l3backend-luatex.def
50      l3backend-luatex.def
51      l3backend-luatex.def
52      l3backend-luatex.def
53      l3backend-luatex.def
54      l3backend-luatex.def
55      l3backend-luatex.def
56      l3backend-luatex.def
57      l3backend-luatex.def
58      l3backend-luatex.def
59      l3backend-luatex.def
60      l3backend-luatex.def
61      l3backend-luatex.def
62      l3backend-luatex.def
63      l3backend-luatex.def
64      l3backend-luatex.def
65      l3backend-luatex.def
66      l3backend-luatex.def
67      l3backend-luatex.def
68      l3backend-luatex.def
69      l3backend-luatex.def
70      l3backend-luatex.def
71      l3backend-luatex.def
72      l3backend-luatex.def
73      l3backend-luatex.def
74      l3backend-luatex.def
75      l3backend-luatex.def
76      l3backend-luatex.def
77      l3backend-luatex.def
78      l3backend-luatex.def
79      l3backend-luatex.def
80      l3backend-luatex.def
81      l3backend-luatex.def
82      l3backend-luatex.def
83      l3backend-luatex.def
84      l3backend-luatex.def
85      l3backend-luatex.def
86      l3backend-luatex.def
87      l3backend-luatex.def
88      l3backend-luatex.def
89      l3backend-luatex.def
90      l3backend-luatex.def
91      l3backend-luatex.def
92      l3backend-luatex.def
93      l3backend-luatex.def
94      l3backend-luatex.def
95      l3backend-luatex.def
96      l3backend-luatex.def
97      l3backend-luatex.def
98      l3backend-luatex.def
99      l3backend-luatex.def
100     l3backend-luatex.def
101     l3backend-luatex.def
102     l3backend-luatex.def
103     l3backend-luatex.def
104     l3backend-luatex.def
105     l3backend-luatex.def
106     l3backend-luatex.def
107     l3backend-luatex.def
108     l3backend-luatex.def
109     l3backend-luatex.def
110     l3backend-luatex.def
111     l3backend-luatex.def
112     l3backend-luatex.def
113     l3backend-luatex.def
114     l3backend-luatex.def
115     l3backend-luatex.def
116     l3backend-luatex.def
117     l3backend-luatex.def
118     l3backend-luatex.def
119     l3backend-luatex.def
120     l3backend-luatex.def
121     l3backend-luatex.def
122     l3backend-luatex.def
123     l3backend-luatex.def
124     l3backend-luatex.def
125     l3backend-luatex.def
126     l3backend-luatex.def
127     l3backend-luatex.def
128     l3backend-luatex.def
129     l3backend-luatex.def
130     l3backend-luatex.def
131     l3backend-luatex.def
132     l3backend-luatex.def
133     l3backend-luatex.def
134     l3backend-luatex.def
135     l3backend-luatex.def
136     l3backend-luatex.def
137     l3backend-luatex.def
138     l3backend-luatex.def
139     l3backend-luatex.def
140     l3backend-luatex.def
141     l3backend-luatex.def
142     l3backend-luatex.def
143     l3backend-luatex.def
144     l3backend-luatex.def
145     l3backend-luatex.def
146     l3backend-luatex.def
147     l3backend-luatex.def
148     l3backend-luatex.def
149     l3backend-luatex.def
150     l3backend-luatex.def
151     l3backend-luatex.def
152     l3backend-luatex.def
153     l3backend-luatex.def
154     l3backend-luatex.def
155     l3backend-luatex.def
156     l3backend-luatex.def
157     l3backend-luatex.def
158     l3backend-luatex.def
159     l3backend-luatex.def
160     l3backend-luatex.def
161     l3backend-luatex.def
162     l3backend-luatex.def
163     l3backend-luatex.def
164     l3backend-luatex.def
165     l3backend-luatex.def
166     l3backend-luatex.def
167     l3backend-luatex.def
168     l3backend-luatex.def
169     l3backend-luatex.def
170     l3backend-luatex.def
171     l3backend-luatex.def
172     l3backend-luatex.def
173     l3backend-luatex.def
174     l3backend-luatex.def
175     l3backend-luatex.def
176     l3backend-luatex.def
177     l3backend-luatex.def
178     l3backend-luatex.def
179     l3backend-luatex.def
180     l3backend-luatex.def
181     l3backend-luatex.def
182     l3backend-luatex.def
183     l3backend-luatex.def
184     l3backend-luatex.def
185     l3backend-luatex.def
186     l3backend-luatex.def
187     l3backend-luatex.def
188     l3backend-luatex.def
189     l3backend-luatex.def
190     l3backend-luatex.def
191     l3backend-luatex.def
192     l3backend-luatex.def
193     l3backend-luatex.def
194     l3backend-luatex.def
195     l3backend-luatex.def
196     l3backend-luatex.def
197     l3backend-luatex.def
198     l3backend-luatex.def
199     l3backend-luatex.def
200     l3backend-luatex.def
201     l3backend-luatex.def
202     l3backend-luatex.def
203     l3backend-luatex.def
204     l3backend-luatex.def
205     l3backend-luatex.def
206     l3backend-luatex.def
207     l3backend-luatex.def
208     l3backend-luatex.def
209     l3backend-luatex.def
210     l3backend-luatex.def
211     l3backend-luatex.def
212     l3backend-luatex.def
213     l3backend-luatex.def
214     l3backend-luatex.def
215     l3backend-luatex.def
216     l3backend-luatex.def
217     l3backend-luatex.def
218     l3backend-luatex.def
219     l3backend-luatex.def
220     l3backend-luatex.def
221     l3backend-luatex.def
222     l3backend-luatex.def
223     l3backend-luatex.def
224     l3backend-luatex.def
225     l3backend-luatex.def
226     l3backend-luatex.def
227     l3backend-luatex.def
228     l3backend-luatex.def
229     l3backend-luatex.def
230     l3backend-luatex.def
231     l3backend-luatex.def
232     l3backend-luatex.def
233     l3backend-luatex.def
234     l3backend-luatex.def
235     l3backend-luatex.def
236     l3backend-luatex.def
237     l3backend-luatex.def
238     l3backend-luatex.def
239     l3backend-luatex.def
240     l3backend-luatex.def
241     l3backend-luatex.def
242     l3backend-luatex.def
243     l3backend-luatex.def
244     l3backend-luatex.def
245     l3backend-luatex.def
246     l3backend-luatex.def
247     l3backend-luatex.def
248     l3backend-luatex.def
249     l3backend-luatex.def
250     l3backend-luatex.def
251     l3backend-luatex.def
252     l3backend-luatex.def
253     l3backend-luatex.def
254     l3backend-luatex.def
255     l3backend-luatex.def
256     l3backend-luatex.def
257     l3backend-luatex.def
258     l3backend-luatex.def
259     l3backend-luatex.def
260     l3backend-luatex.def
261     l3backend-luatex.def
262     l3backend-luatex.def
263     l3backend-luatex.def
264     l3backend-luatex.def
265     l3backend-luatex.def
266     l3backend-luatex.def
267     l3backend-luatex.def
268     l3backend-luatex.def
269     l3backend-luatex.def
270     l3backend-luatex.def
271     l3backend-luatex.def
272     l3backend-luatex.def
273     l3backend-luatex.def
274     l3backend-luatex.def
275     l3backend-luatex.def
276     l3backend-luatex.def
277     l3backend-luatex.def
278     l3backend-luatex.def
279     l3backend-luatex.def
280     l3backend-luatex.def
281     l3backend-luatex.def
282     l3backend-luatex.def
283     l3backend-luatex.def
284     l3backend-luatex.def
285     l3backend-luatex.def
286     l3backend-luatex.def
287     l3backend-luatex.def
288     l3backend-luatex.def
289     l3backend-luatex.def
290     l3backend-luatex.def
291     l3backend-luatex.def
292     l3backend-luatex.def
293     l3backend-luatex.def
294     l3backend-luatex.def
295     l3backend-luatex.def
296     l3backend-luatex.def
297     l3backend-luatex.def
298     l3backend-luatex.def
299     l3backend-luatex.def
300     l3backend-luatex.def
301     l3backend-luatex.def
302     l3backend-luatex.def
303     l3backend-luatex.def
304     l3backend-luatex.def
305     l3backend-luatex.def
306     l3backend-luatex.def
307     l3backend-luatex.def
308     l3backend-luatex.def
309     l3backend-luatex.def
310     l3backend-luatex.def
311     l3backend-luatex.def
312     l3backend-luatex.def
313     l3backend-luatex.def
314     l3backend-luatex.def
315     l3backend-luatex.def
316     l3backend-luatex.def
317     l3backend-luatex.def
318     l3backend-luatex.def
319     l3backend-luatex.def
320     l3backend-luatex.def
321     l3backend-luatex.def
322     l3backend-luatex.def
323     l3backend-luatex.def
324     l3backend-luatex.def
325     l3backend-luatex.def
326     l3backend-luatex.def
327     l3backend-luatex.def
328     l3backend-luatex.def
329     l3backend-luatex.def
330     l3backend-luatex.def
331     l3backend-luatex.def
332     l3backend-luatex.def
333     l3backend-luatex.def
334     l3backend-luatex.def
335     l3backend-luatex.def
336     l3backend-luatex.def
337     l3backend-luatex.def
338     l3backend-luatex.def
339     l3backend-luatex.def
340     l3backend-luatex.def
341     l3backend-luatex.def
342     l3backend-luatex.def
343     l3backend-luatex.def
344     l3backend-luatex.def
345     l3backend-luatex.def
346     l3backend-luatex.def
347     l3backend-luatex.def
348     l3backend-luatex.def
349     l3backend-luatex.def
350     l3backend-luatex.def
351     l3backend-luatex.def
352     l3backend-luatex.def
353     l3backend-luatex.def
354     l3backend-luatex.def
355     l3backend-luatex.def
356     l3backend-luatex.def
357     l3backend-luatex.def
358     l3backend-luatex.def
359     l3backend-luatex.def
360     l3backend-luatex.def
361     l3backend-luatex.def
362     l3backend-luatex.def
363     l3backend-luatex.def
364     l3backend-luatex.def
365     l3backend-luatex.def
366     l3backend-luatex.def
367     l3backend-luatex.def
368     l3backend-luatex.def
369     l3backend-luatex.def
370     l3backend-luatex.def
371     l3backend-luatex.def
372     l3backend-luatex.def
373     l3backend-luatex.def
374     l3backend-luatex.def
375     l3backend-luatex.def
376     l3backend-luatex.def
377     l3backend-luatex.def
378     l3backend-luatex.def
379     l3backend-luatex.def
380     l3backend-luatex.def
381     l3backend-luatex.def
382     l3backend-luatex.def
383     l3backend-luatex.def
384     l3backend-luatex.def
385     l3backend-luatex.def
386     l3backend-luatex.def
387     l3backend-luatex.def
388     l3backend-luatex.def
389     l3backend-luatex.def
390     l3backend-luatex.def
391     l3backend-luatex.def
392     l3backend-luatex.def
393     l3backend-luatex.def
394     l3backend-luatex.def
395     l3backend-luatex.def
396     l3backend-luatex.def
397     l3backend-luatex.def
398     l3backend-luatex.def
399     l3backend-luatex.def
400     l3backend-luatex.def
401     l3backend-luatex.def
402     l3backend-luatex.def
403     l3backend-luatex.def
404     l3backend-luatex.def
405     l3backend-luatex.def
406     l3backend-luatex.def
407     l3backend-luatex.def
408     l3backend-luatex.def
409     l3backend-luatex.def
410     l3backend-luatex.def
411     l3backend-luatex.def
412     l3backend-luatex.def
413     l3backend-luatex.def
414     l3backend-luatex.def
415     l3backend-luatex.def
416     l3backend-luatex.def
417     l3backend-luatex.def
418     l3backend-luatex.def
419     l3backend-luatex.def
420     l3backend-luatex.def
421     l3backend-luatex.def
422     l3backend-luatex.def
423     l3backend-luatex.def
424     l3backend-luatex.def
425     l3backend-luatex.def
426     l3backend-luatex.def
427     l3backend-luatex.def
428     l3backend-luatex.def
429     l3backend-luatex.def
430     l3backend-luatex.def
431     l3backend-luatex.def
432     l3backend-luatex.def
433     l3backend-luatex.def
434     l3backend-luatex.def
435     l3backend-luatex.def
436     l3backend-luatex.def
437     l3backend-luatex.def
438     l3backend-luatex.def
439     l3backend-luatex.def
440     l3backend-luatex.def
441     l3backend-luatex.def
442     l3backend-luatex.def
443     l3backend-luatex.def
444     l3backend-luatex.def
445     l3backend-luatex.def
446     l3backend-luatex.def
447     l3backend-luatex.def
448     l3backend-luatex.def
449     l3backend-luatex.def
450     l3backend-luatex.def
451     l3backend-luatex.def
452     l3backend-luatex.def
453     l3backend-luatex.def
454     l3backend-luatex.def
455     l3backend-luatex.def
456     l3backend-luatex.def
457     l3backend-luatex.def
458     l3backend-luatex.def
459     l3backend-luatex.def
460     l3backend-luatex.def
461     l3backend-luatex.def
462     l3backend-luatex.def
463     l3backend-luatex.def
464     l3backend-luatex.def
465     l3backend-luatex.def
466     l3backend-luatex.def
467     l3backend-luatex.def
468     l3backend-luatex.def
469     l3backend-luatex.def
470     l3backend-luatex.def
471     l3backend-luatex.def
472     l3backend-luatex.def
473     l3backend-luatex.def
474     l3backend-luatex.def
475     l3backend-luatex.def
476     l3backend-luatex.def
477     l3backend-luatex.def
478     l3backend-luatex.def
479     l3backend-luatex.def
480     l3backend-luatex.def
481     l3backend-luatex.def
482     l3backend-luatex.def
483     l3backend-luatex.def
484     l3backend-luatex.def
485     l3backend-luatex.def
486     l3backend-luatex.def
487     l3backend-luatex.def
488     l3backend-luatex.def
489     l3backend-luatex.def
490     l3backend-luatex.def
491     l3backend-luatex.def
492     l3backend-luatex.def
493     l3backend-luatex.def
494     l3backend-luatex.def
495     l3backend-luatex.def
496     l3backend-luatex.def
497     l3backend-luatex.def
498     l3backend-luatex.def
499     l3backend-luatex.def
500     l3backend-luatex.def
501     l3backend-luatex.def
502     l3backend-luatex.def
503     l3backend-luatex.def
504     l3backend-luatex.def
505     l3backend-luatex.def
506     l3backend-luatex.def
507     l3backend-luatex.def
508     l3backend-luatex.def
509     l3backend-luatex.def
510     l3backend-luatex.def
511     l3backend-luatex.def
512     l3backend-luatex.def
513     l3backend-luatex.def
514     l3backend-luatex.def
515     l3backend-luatex.def
516     l3backend-luatex.def
517     l3backend-luatex.def
518     l3backend-luatex.def
519     l3backend-luatex.def
520     l3backend-luatex.def
521     l3backend-luatex.def
522     l3backend-luatex.def
523     l3backend-luatex.def
524     l3backend-luatex.def
525     l3backend-luatex.def
526     l3backend-luatex.def
527     l3backend-luatex.def
528     l3backend-luatex.def
529     l3backend-luatex.def
530     l3backend-luatex.def
531     l3backend-luatex.def
532     l3backend-luatex.def
533     l3backend-luatex.def
534     l3backend-luatex.def
535     l3backend-luatex.def
536     l3backend-luatex.def
537     l3backend-luatex.def
538     l3backend-luatex.def
539     l3backend-luatex.def
540     l3backend-luatex.def
541     l3backend-luatex.def
542     l3backend-luatex.def
543     l3backend-luatex.def
544     l3backend-luatex.def
545     l3backend-luatex.def
546     l3backend-luatex.def
547     l3backend-luatex.def
548     l3backend-luatex.def
549     l3backend-luatex.def
550     l3backend-luatex.def
551     l3backend-luatex.def
552     l3backend-luatex.def
553     l3backend-luatex.def
554     l3backend-luatex.def
555     l3backend-luatex.def
556     l3backend-luatex.def
557     l3backend-luatex.def
558     l3backend-luatex.def
559     l3backend-luatex.def
560     l3backend-luatex.def
561     l3backend-luatex.def
562     l3backend-luatex.def
563     l3backend-luatex.def
564     l3backend-luatex.def
565     l3backend-luatex.def
566     l3backend-luatex.def
567     l3backend-luatex.def
568     l3backend-luatex.def
569     l3backend-luatex.def
570     l3backend-luatex.def
571     l3backend-luatex.def
572     l3backend-luatex.def
573     l3backend-luatex.def
574     l3backend-luatex.def
575     l3backend-luatex.def
576     l3backend-luatex.def
577     l3backend-luatex.def
578     l3backend-luatex.def
579     l3backend-luatex.def
580     l3backend-luatex.def
581     l3backend-luatex.def
582     l3backend-luatex.def
583     l3backend-luatex.def
584     l3backend-luatex.def
585     l3backend-luatex.def
586     l3backend-luatex.def
587     l3backend-luatex.def
588     l3backend-luatex.def
589     l3backend-luatex.def
590     l3backend-luatex.def
591     l3backend-luatex.def
592     l3backend-luatex.def
593     l3backend-luatex.def
594     l3backend-luatex.def
595     l3backend-luatex.def
596     l3backend-luatex.def
597     l3backend-luatex.def
598     l3backend-luatex.def
599     l3backend-luatex.def
600     l3backend-luatex.def
601     l3backend-luatex.def
602     l3backend-luatex.def
603     l3backend-luatex.def
604     l3backend-luatex.def
605     l3backend-luatex.def
606     l3backend-luatex.def
607     l3backend-luatex.def
608     l3backend-luatex.def
609     l3backend-luatex.def
610     l3backend-luatex.def
611     l3backend-luatex.def
612     l3backend-luatex.def
613     l3backend-luatex.def
614     l3backend-luatex.def
615     l3backend-luatex.def
616     l3backend-luatex.def
617     l3backend-luatex.def
618     l3backend-luatex.def
619     l3backend-luatex.def
620     l3backend-luatex.def
621     l3backend-luatex.def
622     l3backend-luatex.def
623     l3backend-luatex.def
624     l3backend-luatex.def
625     l3backend-luatex.def
626     l3backend-luatex.def
627     l3backend-luatex.def
628     l3backend-luatex.def
629     l3backend-luatex.def
630     l3backend-luatex.def
631     l3backend-luatex.def
632     l3backend-luatex.def
633     l3backend-luatex.def
634     l3backend-luatex.def
635     l3backend-luatex.def
636     l3backend-luatex.def
637     l3backend-luatex.def
638     l3backend-luatex.def
639     l3backend-luatex.def
640     l3backend-luatex.def
641     l3backend-luatex.def
642     l3backend-luatex.def
643     l3backend-luatex.def
644     l3backend-luatex.def
645     l3backend-luatex.def
646     l3backend-luatex.def
647     l3backend-luatex.def
648     l3backend-luatex.def
649     l3backend-luatex.def
650     l3backend-luatex.def
651     l3backend-luatex.def
652     l3backend-luatex.def
653     l3backend-luatex.def
654     l3backend-luatex.def
655     l3backend-luatex.def
656     l3backend-luatex.def
657     l3backend-luatex.def
658     l3backend-luatex.def
659     l3backend-luatex.def
660     l3backend-luatex.def
661     l3backend-luatex.def
662     l3backend-luatex.def
663     l3backend-luatex.def
664     l3backend-luatex.def
665     l3backend-luatex.def
666     l3backend-luatex.def
667     l3backend-luatex.def
668     l3backend-luatex.def
669     l3backend-luatex.def
670     l3backend-luatex.def
671     l3backend-luatex.def
672     l3backend-luatex.def
673     l3backend-luatex.def
674     l3backend-luatex.def
675     l3backend-luatex.def
676     l3backend-luatex.def
677     l3backend-luatex.def
678     l3backend-luatex.def
679     l3backend-luatex.def
680     l3backend-luatex.def
681     l3backend-luatex.def
682     l3backend-luatex.def
683     l3backend-luatex.def
684     l3backend-luatex.def
685     l3backend-luatex.def
686     l3backend-luatex.def
687     l3backend-luatex.def
688     l3backend-luatex.def
689     l3backend-luatex.def
690     l3backend-luatex.def
691     l3backend-luatex.def
692     l3backend-luatex.def
693     l3backend-luatex.def
694     l3backend-luatex.def
695     l3backend-luatex.def
696     l3backend-luatex.def
697     l3backend-luatex.def
698     l3backend-luatex.def
699     l3backend-luatex.def
700     l3backend-luatex.def
701     l3backend-luatex.def
702     l3backend-luatex.def
703     l3backend-luatex.def
704     l3backend-luatex.def
705     l3backend-luatex.def
706     l3backend-luatex.def
707     l3backend-luatex.def
708     l3backend-luatex.def
709     l3backend-luatex.def
710     l3backend-luatex.def
711     l3backend-luatex.def
712     l3backend-luatex.def
713     l3backend-luatex.def
714     l3backend-luatex.def
715     l3backend-luatex.def
716     l3backend-luatex.def
717     l3backend-luatex.def
718     l3backend-luatex.def
719     l3backend-luatex.def
720     l3backend-luatex.def
721     l3backend-luatex.def
722     l3backend-luatex.def
723     l3backend-luatex.def
724     l3backend-luatex.def
725     l3backend-luatex.def
726     l3backend-luatex.def
727     l3backend-luatex.def
728     l3backend-luatex.def
729     l3backend-luatex.def
730     l3backend-luatex.def
731     l3backend-luatex.def
732     l3backend-luatex.def
733     l3backend-luatex.def
734     l3backend-luatex.def
735     l3backend-luatex.def
736     l3backend-luatex.def
737     l3backend-luatex.def
738     l3backend-luatex.def
739     l3backend-luatex.def
740     l3backend-luatex.def
741     l3backend-luatex.def
742     l3backend-luatex.def
743     l3backend-luatex.def
744     l3backend-luatex.def
745     l3backend-luatex.def
746     l3backend-luatex.def
747     l3backend-luatex.def
748     l3backend-luatex.def
749     l3backend-luatex.def
750     l3backend-luatex.def
751     l3backend-luatex.def
752     l3backend-luatex.def
753     l3backend-luatex.def
754     l3backend-luatex.def
755     l3backend-luatex.def
756     l3backend-luatex.def
757     l3backend-luatex.def
758     l3backend-luatex.def
759     l3backend-luatex.def
760     l3backend-luatex.def
761     l3backend-luatex.def
762     l3backend-luatex.def
763     l3backend-luatex.def
764     l3backend-luatex.def
765     l3backend-luatex.def
766     l3backend-luatex.def
767     l3backend-luatex.def
768     l3backend-luatex.def
769     l3backend-luatex.def
770     l3backend-luatex.def
771     l3backend-luatex.def
772     l3backend-luatex.def
773     l3backend-luatex.def
774     l3backend-luatex.def
775     l3backend-luatex.def
776     l3backend-luatex.def
777     l3backend-luatex.def
778     l3backend-luatex.def
779     l3backend-luatex.def
780     l3backend-luatex.def
781     l3backend-luatex.def
782     l3backend-luatex.def
783     l3backend-luatex.def
784     l3backend-luatex.def
785     l3backend-luatex.def
786     l3backend-luatex.def
787     l3backend-luatex.def
788     l3backend-luatex.def
789     l3backend-luatex.def
790     l3backend-luatex.def
791     l3backend-luatex.def
792     l3backend-luatex.def
793     l3backend-luatex.def
794     l3backend-luatex.def
795     l3backend-luatex.def
796     l3backend-luatex.def
797     l3backend-luatex.def
798     l3backend-luatex.def
799     l3backend-luatex.def
800     l3backend-luatex.def
801     l3backend-luatex.def
802     l3backend-luatex.def
803     l3backend-luatex.def
804     l3backend-luatex.def
805     l3backend-luatex.def
806     l3backend-luatex.def
807     l3backend-luatex.def
808     l3backend-luatex.def
809     l3backend-luatex.def
810     l3backend-luatex.def
811     l3backend-luatex.def
812     l3backend-luatex.def
813     l3backend-luatex.def
814     l3backend-luatex.def
815     l3backend-luatex.def
816     l3backend-luatex.def
817     l3backend-luatex.def
818     l3backend-luatex.def
819     l3backend-luatex.def
820     l3backend-luatex.def
821     l3backend-luatex.def
) (./a.aux1     a.tex
2       a.tex
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd1      ts1cmr.fd
2       ts1cmr.fd
3       ts1cmr.fd
4       ts1cmr.fd
5       ts1cmr.fd
6       ts1cmr.fd
7       ts1cmr.fd
8       ts1cmr.fd
9       ts1cmr.fd
10      ts1cmr.fd
11      ts1cmr.fd
12      ts1cmr.fd
13      ts1cmr.fd
14      ts1cmr.fd
15      ts1cmr.fd
16      ts1cmr.fd
17      ts1cmr.fd
18      ts1cmr.fd
19      ts1cmr.fd
20      ts1cmr.fd
21      ts1cmr.fd
22      ts1cmr.fd
23      ts1cmr.fd
24      ts1cmr.fd
25      ts1cmr.fd
26      ts1cmr.fd
27      ts1cmr.fd
28      ts1cmr.fd
29      ts1cmr.fd
30      ts1cmr.fd
31      ts1cmr.fd
32      ts1cmr.fd
33      ts1cmr.fd
34      ts1cmr.fd
35      ts1cmr.fd
36      ts1cmr.fd
37      ts1cmr.fd
38      ts1cmr.fd
39      ts1cmr.fd
40      ts1cmr.fd
41      ts1cmr.fd
42      ts1cmr.fd
43      ts1cmr.fd
44      ts1cmr.fd
45      ts1cmr.fd
46      ts1cmr.fd
47      ts1cmr.fd
48      ts1cmr.fd
49      ts1cmr.fd
50      ts1cmr.fd
51      ts1cmr.fd
52      ts1cmr.fd
53      ts1cmr.fd
54      ts1cmr.fd
55      ts1cmr.fd
56      ts1cmr.fd
57      ts1cmr.fd
58      ts1cmr.fd
59      ts1cmr.fd
60      ts1cmr.fd
61      ts1cmr.fd
62      ts1cmr.fd
63      ts1cmr.fd
)10     a.tex
11      a.tex
12      a.tex
13      a.tex
14      a.tex
15      a.tex
16      a.tex
17      a.tex
 [1{/home/user202729/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./
2       a.tex
))
```

Sure, the output is interleaved with the "normal LaTeX output", but you can easily redirect the output to a different file on the Lua side.

Side note: using local TeX loop to read the macro content (`tex.runtoks`) does not work here.

Comment: Alternatively use `texio.write("log", ...)` if you want to write to the log. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337469/write-to-aux-file-directly-from-lua#comment1592311_527387

Comment: This can be modified to print out the time taken by each line to see which part is slow. See https://gist.github.com/user202729/92cbb544b26f027eb0b097cb33c0d867