# Querying the state of a boolean from lua

Tags: luatex, expl3

I can query and use the states of counts in lua without problem. But now I'm wondering how to at best do it with booleans. I have been looking at the token library but it seems not to allow to get and compare the content of a command. Has someone a good idea?

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \g_uf_some_bool
\int_new:N  \g_uf_some_int
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
local catlatex       = luatexbase.registernumber("catcodetable@latex")

function printifzero ()
 if tex.count["g_uf_some_int"]==0  then
  tex.sprint(catlatex,"int is zero")
 else
  tex.sprint(catlatex,"int is " .. tex.count["g_uf_some_int"])
 end
end

function printifbool ()
 -- if g_uf_some_bool  then --???
 tex.sprint(catlatex,"bool is true")
 -- else
 tex.sprint(catlatex,"bool is false")  
 --end
end

\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
\minisec{Integers}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\directlua{printifzero()}

\par
\int_gset:Nn\g_uf_some_int{42}
\directlua{printifzero()}

\minisec{booleans}
\bool_set_true:N \g_uf_some_bool
\directlua{printifbool()}
\par

\bool_set_false:N \g_uf_some_bool
\directlua{printifbool()}
\par

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So that's basically how to compare a macro's value with charcode 0 or 1…

Comment: The fact that a true boolean is `\char"1` and a false one is `\char"0` (the tokens is defined/redefined with `\chardef`) should not be relied upon: it's just the way booleans are internally implemented and it is in principle subject to change.

Comment: @egreg I'm sure Ulrike knows that: probably what is needed is some defined Lua-side interfaces provided by the team

Comment: @JosephWright I found that there is actually a `token.get_macro()` but it doesn't work for booleans, but returns nil. And while there is a `token.set_char()` there is no `token.get_char()` (or if there is something usable, it is well hidden ..).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What about comparing `\g_uf_some_bool` with `\c_true_bool`?

Comment: @egreg the question is how you can do this in lua?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good question! `:-D`

Comment: @egreg I seem to have found a solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I seem to have found an answer. But the used field is not documentated in the luatex manual, I only found it by chance in the context code. So I neither know what it exactly contains, nor if it will be there in the next versions.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \g_uf_some_bool
\int_new:N  \g_uf_some_int
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
local catlatex       = luatexbase.registernumber("catcodetable@latex")
local tbool =token.create("g_uf_some_bool")
local ttrue =token.create("c_true_bool")

function printifzero ()
 if tex.count["g_uf_some_int"]==0  then
  tex.sprint(catlatex,"int is zero")
 else
  tex.sprint(catlatex,"int is " .. tex.count["g_uf_some_int"])
 end
end

function printifbool ()
 if tbool.mode == ttrue.mode  then 
  tex.sprint(catlatex,"bool is true")
 else
  tex.sprint(catlatex,"bool is false")
 end
end


\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
\minisec{Integers}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\directlua{printifzero()}

\par
\int_gset:Nn\g_uf_some_int{42}
\directlua{printifzero()}

\minisec{booleans}
\bool_set_true:N \g_uf_some_bool
\directlua{printifbool()}
\par

\bool_set_false:N \g_uf_some_bool
\directlua{printifbool()}
\par

\bool_set_true:N \g_uf_some_bool
\directlua{printifbool()}
\par
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Browsing the source, I found that there is also [`token.get_mode`](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/48c36a536a6bd3469e682e7e4bc4531817ccea9a/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/lua/lnewtokenlib.c#L1085).

Comment: @HenriMenke did you also found info about what exactly is in property?

Comment: The `mode` is what is called the equivalent value in the TeX source. It's meaning depends on the `command` field, but here it is simple: `expl3` bools are `\chardef`s with value `1` for true, `0` for false. For `\chardef`s, the `mode` is just the character code of the char, so it is `0` or `1`.

Comment: Side note, `token.get_mode(token.create(x))`  can be simplified to `token.create(x).mode`; nevertheless it will probably result in "unpredictable" value when the token is not a chardef. // See [note on newer LuaTeX versions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646457/how-to-implement-token-get-char?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1610818_646463).