# How to access etoolbox toggle inside Lua

Tags: luatex, etoolbox

I'm creating a package that uses `etoolbox` toggles but a good amount of the package is written in Lua. **Is there a way to access the `etoolbox` toggles direct in Lua?**

I know that `etoolbox` uses a separate namespace for it's bools, but I can't find a way to access bools created by `\newif` in Lua either.

---

Minimal (non-)working example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{luacode}

\newtoggle{mytoggle}

\begin{document}
\directlua{
  % Not sure what etoolbox_toggle_true function should be
  if tex.?etoolbox_toggle_true?(\luastring{mytoggle}) then
    tex.print('mytoggle is true!')
  else
    tex.print('mytoggle is false.')
  end
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Distantly related, but probably not the answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438765/35864

Comment: The 'values' of `etoolbox` toggles are either `\etb@toggletrue` or `\etb@togglefalse`. And the toggle `foo` is actually just `\etb@tgl@foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stealing [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s solution to [Querying the state of a boolean from lua](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438765/35864) seems to work. Of course the same caveats apply: It is not clear to me why `mode` (described in [the June 2018/1.0.9 version of the manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/luatex.pdf) in §10.6.3, p. 209 as "a number either representing a character or another entity") is the correct thing to compare.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{foo}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
local catlatex = luatexbase.registernumber("catcodetable@latex")
local mytoggle = token.create("etb@tgl@foo")

function is_etb_toggletrue_tok(toggle)
  local etb_toggle_true = token.create("etb@toggletrue")
  return toggle.mode == etb_toggle_true.mode
end

function is_etb_toggletrue_name(togglename)
  local toggle = token.create("etb@tgl@" .. togglename)
  return is_etb_toggletrue_tok(toggle)
end

function printifbool ()
 if is_etb_toggletrue_name("foo") then 
  tex.sprint(catlatex,"bool is true")
 else
  tex.sprint(catlatex,"bool is false")
 end
end
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
\minisec{booleans}

\toggletrue{foo}
\directlua{printifbool()}

\togglefalse{foo}
\directlua{printifbool()}
\end{document}
```

[image]

We just have to know that `etoolbox` toggles have only two values: `\etb@toggletrue` or `\etb@togglefals` and that the toggle `foo` is  `\etb@tgl@foo`.

The code now has two functions `is_etb_toggletrue_tok` that takes a token as produced by `token_create` or `is_etb_toggletrue_name` that takes a string with the `etoolbox` name of a toggle.

`etb_toggle_true` is assigned on each run of `is_etb_toggletrue_tok`, I'm not sure if that is good practice or not. But I wanted it in the smallest possible scope.