# How to implement token.get_char

Tags: macros, luatex, registers, token

There is a `token.set_char` but no `token.get_char`.
Starting from

```
\chardef\MyNumber=1
```

I can change the value with

```
\directlua{
  token.set_char('MyNumber', 421)
}
```

and retrieve the value on the TeX side

```
\the\MyNumber
```

but how to retrieve the value on the lua side?

I have one solution in mind but it is not satisfying: with `tex.runtoks`, lua can ask tex to copy MyNumber to a dedicated count register, and then retrieve the value using `tex.count`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way is to extract the value from the token using `.index`

```
\directlua{
  local char_given = token.command_id'char_given'
  local function get_char(name)
    local tok = token.create(name)
    if not (tok.command == char_given) then
      error'Not a chardef'
    end
    return tok.index
  end
  token.set_char('MyNumber', 421)
  local restored = get_char'MyNumber'
}
\bye
```

but if you want it to be more generic and also e.g. accepts count registers you can also add the token to the input stream and than scan it as a number:

```
  local function get_char(name)
    token.put_next(token.create(name))
    return token.scan_int()
  end
  token.set_char('MyNumber', 421)
  local restored = get_char'MyNumber'
}
\bye
```

Comment: I thought it's `mode` (last time I tested)... ([luatex - Querying the state of a boolean from lua - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438765/querying-the-state-of-a-boolean-from-lua#comment1609216_438782))

Comment: @user202729 `index` is basically the new version of `mode`. For most commands they are the same, but for some `mode` has some weird offsets which `index` automatically takes care of. So except if you want to be compatible with old LuaTeX versions which didn't have `index` yet, it's almost always better to use `index`. (Also looking forward `index` is compatible with LuaMetaTeX which removed `mode`)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `\directlua` (i.e. no external `.lua` file) then you can get the value from TeX world to the Lua world by expanding it inside the Lua code, because `\directlua` expands its argument before the Lua code is read. For example

```
\directlua{... ... myvariable = \the\MyNumber ... ...}
```

Comment: More precisely, this very simple solution assumes that one wants the value of `\MyNumber` at the time LuaTeX parses the `\directlua` argument and not at the time the assignment instruction `myvariable=...` is executed. +1