# inside an \input file, how to determine the name "\input"ing file?

Tags: jobname

I have two tex files

```
% file1.tex (this is the inputing file)
\input file2
\bye
```

and

```
% file2.tex (this is the file input into file1.tex)
\printTheNameOfWhateverFileInputMe
```

What is working to show the first file name is

% file2.tex (this is the file input into file1.tex)
   \jobname %(this prints "file1")

but this would not work if file2.tex was to be included from file1.tex who is the principle job, hence coincides with `\jobname` not in such a situation

```
% file0.tex
\input file1
\bye

% file1.tex
\input file2

% file2.tex
\jobname %(shows "file0" instead of "file1")
```

Comment: Are you open to LaTeX solutions?

Comment: @Werner yes I think it would help me too

Comment: (see also https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59889991#59889991 )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`currfile`](http://ctan.org/pkg/currfile) provides hooks into filenames:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{currfile,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{file1.tex}
\verb|file1|: \currfilename

\input{file2}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{file2.tex}
\verb|file2|: \currfilename
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\verb|file0|: \jobname .tex

\input{file1}

\end{document}
```

---

You can also capture `\currfilename` for use in another input file, effectively capturing the "parent file". This is provided by the `[parent]` option and using `\parentfilename`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[parent]{currfile}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{file1.tex}
\verb|parent|: \parentfilename \par
\verb|file1|: \currfilename

\input{file2}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{file2.tex}
\verb|parent|: \parentfilename \par
\verb|file2|: \currfilename
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\verb|file0|: \jobname .tex

\input{file1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very much appreciate. When reading the answer I fear I have been not expressing myself well enough. At least it seems to me in each file I am only ever able to track its own filename, which is good by itself.....Anyway it would be much better to be able to tell the filename of the file that `\input` the file currently parsed. In my examples for instance `file2.tex` should get the information `file1.tex`, since it has been input by it.

Comment: @humanityANDpeace: You can capture `\currfilename` in another macro (say `\parentfilename`) to keep it...

Comment: thank you for adding to answer the example to help solve the question/problem. good idea

Comment: @humanityANDpeace the package currfile define  command \parentfilename and even more.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation in `expl3` that works over Plain TeX:

### Main file `hap.tex`

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn

% we implement a stack
\seq_new:N \g_hap_filename_seq
\seq_gput_right:Nx \g_hap_filename_seq { \c_sys_jobname_str }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sinput #1
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_hap_filename_seq { #1 }
  \tex_input:D #1 \scan_stop:
  \seq_gpop_right:NN \g_hap_filename_seq \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\cs_new:Npn \currentfile
 {
  \hap_parent:n { -1 }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \parentfile
 {
  \hap_parent:n { -2 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \hap_parent:n
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \g_hap_filename_seq { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

current file: \currentfile, parent file: \parentfile

\sinput{hap-first}

\bye
```

### Secondary file `hap-first.tex`

```
current file: \currentfile, parent file: \parentfile

\sinput{hap-second}
```

### Secondary file `hap-second.tex`

```
current file: \currentfile, parent file: \parentfile
```

### Output

[image]

---

With just Plain TeX:

```
\newtoks\filestack
\global\filestack={{\jobname}{}}

\def\sinput#1{%
  \edef\sinputtemp{{#1}\the\filestack}%
  \global\filestack=\expandafter{\sinputtemp}%
  %\immediate\write20{Stack: \the\filestack}% for debugging
  \input #1\relax
  \edef\sinputtemp{\expandafter\gobble\the\filestack}%
  \global\filestack=\expandafter{\sinputtemp}%
  %\immediate\write20{Stack: \the\filestack}% for debugging
}
\def\currentfile{\expandafter\firstitem\the\filestack\filestack}
\def\parentfile{\expandafter\seconditem\the\filestack\filestack}
\def\gobble#1{}
\def\firstitem#1#2\filestack{#1}
\def\seconditem#1#2#3\filestack{#2}

current file: \currentfile, parent file: \parentfile

\sinput{hap-first}

\bye
```

Comment: It is a delight that the buzz-word "stack" is found in this answer. I hope that maybe there will be a way to extract the stack-building technique and unlink it from a dependency, i.e hopfully it will allow to design an pure plain tex solution. than you for the intermediated step

Comment: @humanityANDpeace Here it is. :)

Comment: great addition to the answer, I am still at deciphering it and then hope to learn from it, thank you