# Pandoc errors always give the wrong line number

Tags: miktex, pandoc

I've found Pandoc error messages to be completely uninformative, since the line number is always wrong. For example, right now I'm working on a file that is *223* lines long, and Pandoc says there's an error on "line 295" (specifically, it says l.295`. Line 295 obviously does not exist. Is there any way I can fix this? Am I just misinterpreting something?

Comment: the line number of the form `l.295` is from tex not pandoc so will relate to the tex file that pandoc generated (or a file include into that file) not your original source.

Answer (score 1):

You could be calling some macro within your markdown file that uses a package. The arguments passed to that macro is processed and caused an error *within the package code* at line 295.

There's no true way to fix this in general, since the code is most likely *valid* within your document, but not within the package. Moreover, packages can call one another, making for a nested search of lines where mistakes can occur, with calls being valid until they are not. Another example of this is given in [why is this error message line number wrong?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324598/5764)

The proper solution here would be to understand what arguments are being passed to macros and compare that to what is allowed. Certain arguments may be [fragile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5764), for example.