# How to understand which control sequence in undefined in "Undefined control sequence." message?

Tags: luatex

I got `"Undefined control sequence."` message, but from `...sdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(lfs.currentdir())}` I do not understand, on which control sequence LuaLaTeX refers:

[image]

How can I explore it?

The MWE is

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}

\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(lfs.currentdir())}/}

\begin{document}
    done
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your file compiles without errors for me (TL 2018).

Comment: @AlanMunn, Thank you for try. Did you compile by LuaLaTeX? It's interesting, what I missed. I'll upload a screencast later.

Comment: Use `tex.sprint(-2,lfs.currentdir())` to switch to verbatim catcodes.

Comment: @HenriMenke, Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, It will delete path separators, and `C:Users/me/Documents/TeX/LuaLaTeX_Development/fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc` becomes to `C:UsersmeDocumentsTeXLuaLaTeX_Development/fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The undefined control sequence is the thing just before the line break:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\quad\acommandthatdoesntexist\quad
\end{document}
```

Has the output:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> \quad\acommandthatdoesntexist
                    \quad
```

In your case, that appears to be `\Users`, which may suggest that TeX is trying to read a Windows path and interpreting the `\` as beginning a command.  You'll probably need a package that can navigate Windows directories.

Comment: Side note, there are some special cases where the thing just before line break is not the undefined control sequence. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/627520/250119

Answer (score 5):

The undefined control sequence is `\Users` which is part of the path.  Even though here `\` is meant to be the path separator, LuaTeX doesn't know that and just feeds the path with the currently active catcodes back to TeX, where `\` happens to be the escape characters.  Luckily, you can tell `tex.sprint` to use a different catcode table using an optional argument.  To use verbatim catcodes (everything is catcode 12, except space which retains catcode 10) use the catcode table with number `-2`.

```
\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(-2, lfs.currentdir())}/}
```

Comment: That why I did not understand... You have the deep understanding. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: I checked your solution. Unfortunately, it will delete path separators, and `C:Users/me/Documents/TeX/LuaLaTeX_Development/fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc` becomes to `C:UsersmeDocumentsTeXLuaLaTeX_Development/fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc`.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu You probably need another font.  Try `\texttt{\currfileabsdir}`.