# LuaLaTeX: How to correctly resolve absolute path with \directlua on Windows

Tags: fonts, luatex, lua, filesystem-access

I need to resolve absolute path to fonts:

```
\setmainjfont[
    Path          = \currfileabsdir,
    UprightFont   = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc,
    BoldFont      = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRME.ttc
]{HGS Mincho}
```

The solution `\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}` requires `-recorder` option, but I don't use console, and setup `-recorder` option is potentially unnecessary routine.

Other solution based on `lfs` library, but if we just use it as shown below, error will occur (at least, in Windows):

```
\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(lfs.currentdir())}/}
```

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 C:\Users
          \i\Documents\TeX\LuaLaTeX_Development
l.6 ...sdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(lfs.currentdir())}
                                                  /}
```

[It was recommended](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482030/31274) to use catcodes as shown below:

```
\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(-2, lfs.currentdir())}/}
```

What really will be is backslashes will be removed from absolute path, so

```
C:Users/i/Documents/TeX/LuaLaTeX_Development/fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc
```

becomes to

```
C:UsersmeDocumentsTeXLuaLaTeX_Development/fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc
```

How I get correct absolute path to font?

---

### Update: MWE with first suggested solution

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}

\makeatletter
\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(\the\catcodetable@string, lfs.currentdir())}/}
\makeatother

\setmainjfont[
    Path          = \currfileabsdir,
    UprightFont   = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc,
    BoldFont      = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRME.ttc
]{HGS Mincho}

\setsansjfont[
    Path          = \currfileabsdir,
    UprightFont   = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGM.ttc,
    BoldFont      = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGE.ttc,
]{HGS Gothic}


\begin{document}
  日本語文字  Latin letters Кириллица
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: "File not found: C:UsersiDocumentsTeXLuaLaTeX_Development/fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc.".

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.13 ]{HGS Mincho}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails as the backslash used on windows in the path is in lua also the escape char. As the path is passed on to the lua backend one need to escape the backslash with another backslash. You can use \luaescapestring for this.

```
\edef\currfileabsdir{\luaescapestring{\directlua{tex.sprint(-2,lfs.currentdir())}}/}
```

Or if you want to use \currfileabsdir also in other places, add the `\luaescapestring` to the `Path`:

```
\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(-2,lfs.currentdir())}/}
\setmainjfont[
   Path          = \luaescapestring{\currfileabsdir},
   ....
```

Comment: There must be something else wrong with OP's code, which they haven't told us.  Catcode table `-2` is hardcoded: https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/eafe6e149e78c13abb435e5c1e06bb49aa59e414/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/textoken.h#L123

Comment: @HenriMenke yes I guess too. That's why I showed a complete example ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, nothing changed. I added MWE with your solution in question filed. Please, take a look.

Comment: Add \show\currfileabsdir directly after the \makeatother, compile, (hit enter when it stops at the \show) and then show the log-file.

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you for the answer! Accept and vote-up.