# How to use \errorcontextlines interactively?

Tags: tex-core

On p.34 of *TeXbook* it is said:

> By setting
>   `\errorcontextlines=0` at the beginning of your file, you can reduce the amount of
>   information that is reported; TEX will show only the top and bottom pairs of context
>   lines together with up to `\errorcontextlines` additional two-line items. (If anything
>   has thereby been omitted, you’ll also see ‘`...`’.) Chances are good that you can
>   spot the source of an error even when most of a large context has been suppressed; if
>   not, you can say ‘`I\errorcontextlines=100\oops`’ and try again. (That will usually
>   give you an undefined control sequence error and plenty of context.)

Let's try it by modifying line 3 of `story.tex` like this:

```
\errorcontextlines=0 \centerline{\bf A SHORT \ERROR STORY}
```

TeX stops with this error (one pair of context lines is omitted due to setting of `\errorcontextlines`):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \bf A SHORT \ERROR 
                              STORY
...
l.3 ...nes=0 \centerline{\bf A SHORT \ERROR STORY}
```

Now suppose I want to see the omitted pair of context lines. According to above extract from *TeXbook* I type in response to `?`:

```
I\errorcontextlines=100\oops
```

But instead of something like this

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \bf A SHORT \ERROR 
                              STORY
\centerline #1->\line {\hss #1
                              \hss }
l.3 ...nes=5 \centerline{\bf A SHORT \ERROR STORY}
```

I get this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<insert>   \errorcontextlines=100\oops

...
l.3 ...nes=0 \centerline{\bf A SHORT \ERROR STORY}
```

Why I do not get the omitted context by changing `\errorcontextlines` interactively?

Comment: Future users coming across this question may be looking for [macros - What does \errorcontextlines do? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35252/what-does-errorcontextlines-do) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have found a bug in *The TeXbook*: there's a space missing. It works if you enter `I\errorcontextlines=100 \oops`. That is, after TeX has shown:

```
(./story.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \bf A SHORT \ERROR 
                              STORY
...
l.3 ...nes=0 \centerline{\bf A SHORT \ERROR STORY}
?
```

you can enter `I\errorcontextlines=100 \oops` to get:

```
? I\errorcontextlines=100 \oops
! Undefined control sequence.
<insert>   \errorcontextlines=100 \oops

<argument> \bf A SHORT \ERROR 
                              STORY
\centerline #1->\line {\hss #1
                              \hss }
l.3 ...nes=0 \centerline{\bf A SHORT \ERROR STORY}

?
```

The idea is that in the inserted token list (what you typed), TeX has to first read `\errorcontextlines=100` (and process it, i.e. perform the assignment), before encountering the `\oops` and showing an undefined control sequence error again. But with `\errorcontextlines=100\oops`, it does not stop scanning a number at `100` and tries to expand `\oops` in case it expands to something starting with a sequence of digits, so the error is different, and more importantly, the error is encountered before the `\errorcontextlines=` command is processed/acted upon. (So it has no effect.)

Comment: Yes, this is what I came up with before seeing your answer.