# Conditional inclusion of environment gives random errors

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, tikz-external

I've spent a few hours trying to debug the following.
I did manage to fix it, but mostly by chance.
Can someone enlighten me on what actually happened?

## Initial setup

I'm using `\usetikzlibrary{external}`.
I `\input` the same file multiple times, which generates a `pgfplots` graph.
Sometimes I want to display a secondary axis, so this file looks something like this:

```
\tikzset{external/export next=false}  % since I'm running it multiple times
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Primary axis and charts
…

% Optional secondary axis and charts
\ifSecondaryAxis
\begin{axis}
…
\end{axis}  % line 58
\fi

\end{tikzpicture}
```

This was creating nasty errors for the following pictures which didn't have the `\tikzset{external/export next=false}` directive.
This was extremely hard to trace back, since the breaking code effect was observed on later figures externalisation.
For example, I was getting the following error on a random `spiral-pred_dec.tex`:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "pdf-tikz-figs/spiral-pred_dec" "\def\tikz externalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'pdf -tikz-figs/spiral-pred_dec' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:).
```

Commenting out `spiral-pred_dec.tex` was giving an error on the following picture, and so on.

What fixed everything (and here comes the question) has been *adding a pair of curly brackets around the `axis` environment*, so to have something like:

```
% Optional secondary axis and charts
\ifSecondaryAxis
{\begin{axis}
…
\end{axis}}
\fi
```

## Question

What does adding a pair of curly brackets around an environment accomplish, when dealing with TeX conditional rendering?

## Additional debugging information

```
) (./ellipse-figs/E23.tex)
! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 58.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.131     \input{ellipse-figs/E23}
                                  % 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
…

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

And line `58` corresponds to `\end{axis}` in the first code snippet, one line above the `\fi`.

Comment: Perhaps there's sth useful in `pdf-tikz-figs/spiral-pred_dec.log`.

Comment: Without a minimal working example it's quite impossible to tell... but generally speaking you can't arbitrarily include command A inside command B, but TeX evaluates from outside to inside so command B will "see" command A and might do something different.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, I've added the content of the `log` relative to the breaking part. @user202729, I could try to put together a minimal working example, but I've already found a fix. So, I'm here just to get some pointers about the behaviour of conditionals interacting with arbitrary environments, just in case there's something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: How about `\makeatletter \newcommand\ifSecondaryAxisT{\ifSecondaryAxis \expandafter\@firstofone \else \expandafter\@gobble \fi} \makeatother` then `\ifSecondaryAxis{\begin{axis} ... \end{axis}}`?

Comment: For one, if there's some _token_ with _meaning_ (← read TeXbook etc. if the terms doesn't make sense) equal to `\fi` or `\iftrue` etc.   then it may mess up the expansion. (I consider this unlikely) Then, the conditional leave the \fi token after, which might be problematic if the environment for some weird reason look after the token list. (see ^ && [macros - What do \@firstoftwo and \@secondoftwo do? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21262/what-do-firstoftwo-and-secondoftwo-do/21263#21263)) for explanation on this point)

Comment: Look, remote debugging isn't going to work, but at least give us the more complete traceback (enable error context lines [macros - What does \errorcontextlines do? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35252/what-does-errorcontextlines-do/))

Comment: Another possibility would be that it undo some local assignment etc.  (read e.g. "the grouping mechanism" in TeX by topic)